# How do permissions on deferred transactions work?

Tags: action, permissions, deferred-transactions, authorization

I'm playing around with deferred transactions and encountered an oddity.

Say, we have a contract deployed on `contract`, and an account `account`.
`contract` has `contract@eosio.code` as part of its active permission, `account` does **not**.

The EOS Portal developer documentation states:

> Deferred transactions carry the authority of the contract that sends them.

In my deferred action handler I `require_auth(account)` and it passes.
Shouldn't it fail as the transaction has authorization contract@eosio.code and thus fail as account@active does not contain contract@eosio.code?

If I add a deferred transaction to transfer eosio.token it however does not correctly pass the authorization check.

```
Exception Details: 3090003 unsatisfied_authorization: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"account","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 3000 ms, provided permissions [{"actor":"contract","permission":"eosio.code"}], and provided keys []
    {"auth":{"actor":"account","permission":"active"},"provided_delay":3000,"provided_permissions":[{"actor":"contract","permission":"eosio.code"}],"provided_keys":[],"delay_max_limit_ms":3888000000}
```

Why does one `require_auth` check pass, but the other doesn't?
Here's the code I deploy on `contract`

```
#include <string>
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/transaction.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/currency.hpp>

using namespace eosio;
using namespace std;

class deferred_example : public eosio::contract
{
public:
    deferred_example(account_name self) : contract(self)
    {
    }

    /// @abi action
    void deferred(account_name from, const string &message)
    {
        // why does this pass? shouldn't the permission be contract@eosio.code
        // and thus fail as from@active does not contain contract@eosio.code?
        require_auth(from);

        print("Printing deferred ", eosio::name{from}, " : ",  message);
    }

    /// @abi action
    void send(account_name from, const string &message)
    {
        require_auth(from);

        eosio::transaction t{};

        // sending this passes the require_auth(from) check in _self::deferred
        t.actions.emplace_back(
            permission_level(from, N(active)),
            _self,
            N(deferred),
            std::make_tuple(from, message));

        // sending this fails the require_auth(from) check in eosio.token::transfer
        // because from@active does not contain contract@eosio.code to 
        // t.actions.emplace_back(permission_level(from, N(active)),
            // N(eosio.token),
            // N(transfer),
            // currency::transfer{
                // .from = from,
                // .to = _self,
                // .quantity = asset(10000, S(4, EOS)),
                // .memo = "transfer EOS"});

        t.delay_sec = 3;
        // use now() as sender id for ease of use
        t.send(now(), from);

        print("Deferred transaction scheduled");
    }
};

EOSIO_ABI(deferred_example, (send)(deferred))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would refer to this: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3013

It looks like Dawn 4.0 changed the permissions a contract needs to call another contract.   You need to grant account@eosio.code permissions to the contract you are calling from "account".